# Run A PHP function only 30% of Time

Tags: php

I need help creating PHP code to echo and run a function only 30% of the time.

Currently I have code below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if (mt_rand(1, 3) == 2)
{
    echo '';
    theFunctionIWantCalled();
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  What's the output from `mt_rand()`?

Comment: Because it's random, it wont necessarily be 30% of the time. It might run 10 times and all 10 times randomly return 2 and therefore echos 100% of the time...

Comment: it could work a billion times in a row, and still be random

Comment: One piece I'm confused on - you're not actually trying to call "function();" are you? If you're posting an example function, rename it to something more descriptive like "theFunctionIWantCalled()"

Comment: sorry to cinfuse anyone but its theFunctionIWantCalled(); not funtion();

Comment: To give a good answer you'll have to provide more context; what are the reason for running it 3/10's of the time? What should be done the other times? Are we talking inside one single request where all tasks should be performed, or should it be distributed evenly across time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using rand you can't guarantee it will be called 30% of the time.  Where you could instead use modulus which will effectively give you 1/3 of the time, not sure how important this is for you but...

```
$max = 27;

for($i = 1; $i < $max; $i++){
    if($i % 3 == 0){
        call_function_here();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this run the same function multiple times in one session? What if a function needed to be run no more than once, but with a 30% chance of actually running?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to echo what the function returns? That would be

```
if(mt_rand(1,100) <= 30)
{
    echo function();
}
```

What you currently have echoes a blank statement, then executes a function. I also changed the random statement. Since this is only pseudo-random and not true randomness, more options will give you a better chance of hitting it 30% of the time.

If you intended to echo a blank statement, then execute a function,

```
if(mt_rand(1,100) <= 30)
{
    echo '';
    function();
}
```

would be correct. Once again, I've changed the if-statement to make it more evenly distributed. To help insure a more even distribution, you could even do

```
if(mt_rand(1,10000) <= 3000)
```

since we aren't dealing with true randomness here. It's entirely possible that the algorithm is choosing one number more than others. As was mentioned in the comments of this question, since the algorithm is random, it could be choosing the same number over, and over, and over again. However, in practice, having more numbers to choose from will most likely result in an even distribution. Having only 3 numbers to choose from can skew the results.

Comment: Im not looking for randomness i just want to run my code around %30 of the time.

Comment: How would i increase that to %45 ?

Comment: But you are using a random function. This random function could be calling 1 or 3 100% of the time rather than 2 30% of the time. If you have a wider range of numbers to choose from, in practice, there is a higher probability that your function will run 30% of the time.

Comment: You could increase it to 45% by changing your if statement to something like `if(mt_rand(1,100) <= 45){ executed code;}`.

Comment: No, it will not be "more random", and no, it won't result in a more even distribution as long as you're treating it as 3 buckets anyway.

Comment: when i test this it run 3.50% of the time

Comment: @fiskfisk sorry, I changed the wording. With true randomness, this won't change the distribution, but with psuedo-randomness, smaller numbers can end with oddly skewed results. It's a pain in PHP.

Comment: @astonishin it may only be randomly selecting it 3.50% of the time, or your numbers may be incorrect. The other answer has a better solution for choosing it *exactly* 30% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Since modulus does not work with floats you can use fmod, this code should be fairly close you can substitute the total iterations and percent...

```
$total = 50;
$percent = 0.50;

$calls = $total * $percent;
$interval = $total / $calls;

$called = 0;
$notcalled = 0;

for($i = 0; $i <= $total; $i++){
    if(fmod($i, $interval) < 1){
        $called++;
        echo "Called" . "\n";
    }else{
        $notcalled++;
        echo "Not Called" . "\n";
    }
}

echo "Called:  " . $called . "\n";
echo "Not Called: " . $notcalled . "\n";
```